Connection error while using requests module in PyCharm
I'm trying to get the location of the ISS using an API.
I imported Python's requests module and tried to use the ISS API using requests.get, but I'm getting this error:

Code:
import requests
response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json")


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

using this code i am trying get ISS JSON data. which i can use further to locate ISS when it is near by my location. as of now this 2 line code only giving this error
